# Send Mail thru cloud function over cloud bucket changes

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, sendmail

I was trying to configure cloud functions to send out mails whenever file gets pushed into one of our cloud buckets in GCP without using third-party tools. I've reviewed the concepts here and made sure my sender email already registered as the authorized sender.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api

`requirements.txt` has below values added:

```
google-cloud-storage==1.23.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.3.5
google-api-python-client
```

in the requirements file. But still getting the same error.

However when I tried using below scripts and it ended up with this error:

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine' .`

Appreciate your suggestions and help in advance.

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.api import mail
import webapp2


def send_approved_mail(sender_address):
    # [START send_mail]
    mail.send_mail(sender=sender_address,
                   to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
                   subject="Your account has been approved",
                   body="""Dear Albert:
Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.
Please let us know if you have any questions.
The example.com Team
""")
    # [END send_mail]


class SendMailHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        send_approved_mail('{}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'.format(
            app_identity.get_application_id()))
        self.response.content_type = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Sent an email to Albert.')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/send_mail', SendMailHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: You said you're trying to use Cloud Functions but this looks like an App Engine app. The `google.appengine` module is only available in the App Engine runtime. I'd recommend looking at the example at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid

Comment: Thanks Dustin. Yes I was trying it in different ways to see if this could be done without using third-party services like sendgrid.

Comment: However I dont seem to find any references where mails can be sent thru cloud function by only using gcp resources. If there are no other ways around then I will start using third party services for our requirements. Thank you

Comment: Sendgrid is the recommended solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to integrate with a third-party email service such as Sendgrid, and structure your Cloud Function as a Cloud Function, for example:

```py
# using SendGrid's Python Library
# https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))

def send_mail(data, context):
    message = Mail(
        from_email='from_email@example.com',
        to_emails='to@example.com',
        subject='This is the subject',
        html_content='This is the content'
    )
    response = sg.send(message)
```

See https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, Dustin. It worked with Sendgrid

Comment: The recommended link https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid in the answer seems to be not avialbale now. Can you provide some other reference to the same?

Comment: I've updated the link to https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf